# CSS | Position sticky not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, css, sticky, intersection-observer

I want to add a specific class to the element when it's sticky position condition matches.
I am using Intersection Observation API to check when the element gets it's sticky position. Code is working fine in all Browsers except for IE11. I have added polyfill for Intersection Observation API for IE.

```
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    // no intersection with screen
    if(entries[0].intersectionRatio === 0)
        document.querySelector("#nav-container").classList.add("nav-container-sticky");
    // fully intersects with screen
    else if(entries[0].intersectionRatio === 1)
        document.querySelector("#nav-container").classList.remove("nav-container-sticky");
}, { threshold: [0,1] });
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/Lbjymag7/) is the fiddle for above scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Position sticky does not work on IE11, not even with prefix ([caniuse.com: sticky](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky)).

Comment: yes ie11 not supports it but   with the help of stickyfill polyfill , we can use position:sticky

Answer (score 1):

Polyfill: stickyfill https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stickyfill/2.1.0/stickyfill.min.js  can be used here.
Also below initialization logic needs to be added:

```
var element = document.querySelector('#nav-container');
Stickyfill.add(element);
```